# Progressive disclosure widgets for very long pages

Tags: website-design, design-patterns, portfolio, progressive-disclosure

I'm facing this challenge with my personal portfolio: how to make a long case study more digestible to compensate for too much content that causes a lot of vertical scrolling.

Current website prototype: https://daniel-portfolio.netlify.com/case/blacktrax-website

One of the my ideas is to use another navigation layer for case study subsections. Either as a side navigation or a top nav sub-navigation.

References:
Bootstrap 4
http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#tables-contextual-classes
[image]

Smartisan OS
https://www.smartisan.com/os/#/powerful
[image]

Smartisan OS-6
https://www.smartisan.com/os/#/6-x

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on the horizontal scrolling problem? Because I don’t understand how the widgets above solve this.

Comment: It's quite hard to extract exactly what it is you're asking.

Comment: It's actually vertical scrolling (typo). The idea of the widget is to make main sections of the case (Discovery - Research - Design - Outcome) more accessible if the reader wants to jump to a specific section. I would also allow the reader to get an idea of how many sections they still need to go through until the case is done.

Comment: So, are you asking whether document outline is a good solution to help user manage long pages? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML_sections_and_outlines#The_HTML5_outline_algorithm

If so, please edit your post to contain the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve your problem improving typography and separating your text in smaller paragraphs. As you can see in http://simonpan.com/work/uber, there is a lot of text, but it is so well organized that it is easy to read. You could use a bigger font size, and insert some quote phrases between longer paragraphs, like in this image from the same page:

[image]

Comment: That will certainly help. But I will still have a lot of scrolling. Question: when you read his case, did you actually read the whole thing from beginning to end like you were reading a book or did you scan the page?

Comment: I scanned the page, and read the parts that caught my attention, like the titles, quotes, and enumerated lists.
About the scrolling, It can get tiresome, but if you keep the content interesting, avoiding repetition, adding some animations, keeping the user intriged about what comes next, I'm sure they will at least scan the whole page.